# Help understanding branch cuts in inverse trig functions.

Tags: complex-analysis

**Background**: I'm trying to solve a [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1878633/evaluate-int-c-overlinezdz-using-parametrization-z-sqrt4-y2iy-2) that people tried to help with. I've got almost what I need from good posts like [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/327120/understanding-branch-cuts-for-functions-with-multiple-branch-points), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/964082/derive-branch-cuts-for-log-sqrt1-z2-iz-as-infty-1-and-1-inft?rq=1).
When you look at functions like $\sqrt{(z-a)(z-b)}$ You can recognize the branch cuts graphically around the circles of the roots  $\sqrt{|z-a|e^{i \arg(z-a)} |z-b|e^{i \arg(z-b)}}$ and figure out the interval where the two jumps cancel. Is there a comprehensible way to visualize the inverse trig function's branch cut in the same way?

> Plot3D[Re[Sinh[x + I y]], {x, -20, 20}, {y, -20, 20},   AxesLabel ->
> Automatic]

As you can see the real part sinh $\frac{e^z-e^{-z}}{2i}$ traces out a sin wave along the y axis, and an exponential $e^{|x|}$ along the x-axis. The Im[sinh] traces out a cos wave along the y axis with an similar looking graph.

[image]

The Real part of the inverse $\sinh^{-1}=\ln|z+(z^2+1)^{1/2}|$ is taking the infinite positive and negative z axis above and mapping it to a restricted x valued  z-height. Branch cut $(-i\infty,-i)$,$(i,i\infty)$

[image]

The imaginary inverse sinh =$iArg(z+(z^2+1)^{1/2}$ appears as follows with the branch cut :

> Plot3D[Im[ArcSinh[(x + I y)]], {x, -20, 20}, {y, -20, 20},   AxesLabel
> -> Automatic]

[image]

Is there any intuitive way to understand the branch cut?